# Convert file.ts to file.aac with ffmeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new at this point, could you tell me to convert file.ts to file.aac through FFmpeg and using this below command to convert from my command prompt.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i file.ts -acodec copy file.aac
```

and I'm getting this as error:

```
[NULL @ 000002693d53d380] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'file.aac'
file.aac: Invalid argument
```

Thank you

Comment: Your command should work as is assuming `file.ts` has AAC audio. Is this the complete command, or did you omit additional options?

Comment: As you can see for me now it's working with this same code (I don't know how) and I found this new code too for conversion which I've answered. And Yes my file.ts has AAC audio so by copying the codec I'm getting the aac file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer

-a is for audio codec and "copy" is for copying the same stream

```
ffmpeg.exe -i file.ts -acodec copy file.aac
```

In the below command -f is for format and -y is for yes accepting the overriding

```
ffmpeg.exe -i file.ts -f adts -y file.aac
```

Comment: No need for `-f adts` when outputting .aac. It will automatically choose `-f adts` for .aac.